# 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Data type mismatch in criteria expression.' error

Tags: c#, ms-access

When I run the program and input the login details, after pressing the login button I get this error:

> "Data type mismatch in criteria expression." at this expression dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

I'm new at this. What to do?

```
namespace Inventory_System
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
      private OleDbConnection mycon;
      private OleDbDataReader dr=null;
      private OleDbCommand cmd=null;
      public MainForm()
      {
        mycon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\User\Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\Inventory System\inventory.mdb;Persist Security Info=False");
        InitializeComponent();  
      }
      void Button2Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        this.Close();
      }
      void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        mycon.Open();
        string cmdstr = "SELECT password FROM admin WHERE ID ='"+textBox1.Text+"' ";
        cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdstr, mycon);
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        string[] login = new string[3];

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            login[3] = (dr["password"].ToString());
        }

        dr.Close();
        mycon.Close();

         if (maskedTextBox1.Text == login[3])
        {
           MessageBox.Show("LOG-IN SUCCESFUL!", "Confirmation Message");
           Form control = new MainForm();
           control.Show();
           this.Hide();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("LOG-IN FAILED!", "Confirmation Message");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: If Id is numeric, you are passing text.  Use SQL Parameters always; never ever store passwords as plaintext - hash them.

Answer (score 1):

Password is a *reserved* word, thus it must be bracketed:

```
string cmdstr = "SELECT [password] FROM admin WHERE ID ='"+textBox1.Text+"'";
```